# UINavigationBar Flash on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Whenever my application is launched (only on iPad) the navigation bar flashes white briefly then pops into it's bar tint color. You can view an animated gif here:

[image]

I am setting the tint on a UINavigationController subclass and this config works perfectly on iPhone.

```
//This returns a UIColor
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [[IGVThemeManager sharedManager] themeColor];

self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20]};
```

I've also tried removing the subclass and manually setting the bar tint color via Interface Builder and still have the same "flash" results. Any ideas on what else may be causing this? This happens on the simulator and on device. Note: this navigation controller exists as part of a split view controller if that helps with any ideas.

Comment: I have made tons of universal apps with custom tint and colors for UINavigation bar and they never behave the way you see. I don't know what IGVThemeManager is? Could it be related to code in that?

Comment: Hey @SamBudda, thanks for replying, I've never run into this either... This is all the related code with IGVThemeManager: https://gist.github.com/jaysonlane/4f11ae60048ebc0d7176 also I've tried it as just a static UIColor with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you code into:

`- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code that you currently have and try adding this to your appdeletgate.m. If it still flashes then there is something else going on.

Note: In order to color my navigation bar I added a blue image to it. The text colors are white

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

UIImage *NavigationPortraitBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_color_header_pic"];

// Set the background image all UINavigationBars
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationPortraitBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



// Set the text appearance for navbar
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
  [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:21], UITextAttributeFont,
  nil]];


NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [UIColor whiteColor],
                            UITextAttributeTextColor,
                            [UIColor whiteColor],
                            UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState: UIControlStateNormal];


// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late - I was having the same issue and could not figure out why. I was calling:

```
  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

I had needed that for a different view that I had used for a template and accidentally left that in there. Removing this call fixed it.